# PrimeFaces p:selectOneMenu width

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I want `p:selectOneMenu` width to be auto regarding to the parent cell not regarding to the values it has.

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <p:row>
        <p:column><p:outputLabel value="Value01" for="idInput01"/></p:column>
        <p:column><p:inputText  value="#{bean.input01}" id="idInput01" /></p:column>
        <p:column><p:outputLabel value="Value02" for="idSelect" /></p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedObject}" id="idSelect" converter="objectConverter">
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.objectsList}" var="varObject" itemLabel="#{varObject.label}" itemValue="#{varObject}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

**What I've got :**

[image]

**What I'm expecting :**

[image]

**Note: I don't want to specify a fixed width.**

Comment: Edited answer should work now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**i overrode** `.ui-selectonemenu, .ui-selectonemenu-label` to:

```
.ui-selectonemenu{
     width: 100% !important;
}
.ui-selectonemenu-label{
     width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: but i has another problem; that it expands to contain all the text it has!

Comment: i dnot know jQury well, so i passed your reply, sorry again

Answer (score 18):

My solution:  autoWidth="false"

Comment: That is no solution at all.
Taking autoWith from the selectOneMenu has the effect that primefaces stops adding the with information to the div and label elements that the select one menu renderer pumps to the HTML.

If that works for you, it most likely means you have some parent .css seting a minum with on input fields. And that value is probably higher and it looks better. If you had no such cross cutting CSS you would be out of luck, odds are. The problem seems to be that pimrefaces 6.0 has a bug in autoWidth computation. Not figured yet where.

Comment: This bug is most likely fixed in some 6.X release.
In the community edition for 6.0 - the min-wdth that goes out into the drop-down div is 100% impoperly calculated. It seems to be calculated based on the selected element on the drop down and not on the fattest label.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I found is to use `jQuery` to initialize width at load time.

You can create simply a CSS class like this (just to be used as a futur **selector**) :

```
.full-width
{

}
```

And add it to your component :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedObject}" id="idSelect" converter="objectConverter" styleClass="full-width">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.objectsList}" var="varObject"  itemLabel="{varObject.label}" itemValue="#{varObject}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Since you will need **jQuery**, you should add this inside your `h:head` if you are not already using **PrimeFaces** components that use it.

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

Here is the small script that initialize all p:selectOneMenu in the selector :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $("div.ui-selectonemenu.full-width").each(
                function()
                {
                    $(this).css("width",$(this).parent().width());
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work that way, although it is a natural way of doing so, as select element will be wrapped by a bunch of 'helper' tags created by PF. PrimeFaces somehow calculates width of these additional blocks and there is some bug inside JS implementation. Tested with two rows and two PF select tags with varying item label length. So I basically don't know the solution to the problem.

Comment: @skuntsel I'm still not using PrimeFaces, does it render a plain `<select />` ? I don't think so by your comment! :(

Comment: That's true. Select is hidden, and the dropdown itself is rendered as a `div` with `ul`/`li` styled. So the `width:100%` works only harmlessly in case there is one `<p:selectOneMenu>` is a table. Moreover, PF *may* override CSS class by inline style's width.

Comment: I've tested on PrimeFaces showcase with Firebug and we need to change width of two elements with 16px width difference between them at least... bad thing. They should include a `width` attribute.

Comment: Double those problems when using tables with multiple dropdowns. My test confirmed that order matters, as well as how and where you put that `width`. Ultimately, there are UI problems when you assign width in a non-expected by PF way, as well as do some typing in a dropdown, and that is an empty gray space filled between text section and down arrow button.

Comment: One way I'm thinking is about to set one item in the list example "Select an option" to be the same for all components in the table so they will at least be the same width if this item is the largest.

Comment: @skuntsel answer edited, and tested, I've now installed PrimeFaces for the first time :)

Comment: Welcome to the club Alex! :) I also assured that you can't evade JS on this one. And, of course, an upvote!

Answer (score 5):

you can add the value of width directly in the component to modify it, to avoid impacting other p: selectOneMenu existing in the page.

```
<p:selectOneMenu  style="width: 100% !important">
...
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 3):

I now have a proper fix for this.

Primefaces 6.0 now has a new field called autoWidth that by default is set to true, and you can set to false.

IF you do as some of the above responses say and set it to false, all you are doing is playing roulette with you app css.
By setting it to false, primefaces will leave it up to you to manage the width.
You can either have the width set on the selectOneMeny expliclitly by style attribute, or some css class in your application.

But this is not what this issue is about, this issue is about the fact that the default behaivor of not specifying any width to a drop down makes leads our drop downs to normally be way too small for the labels in there.

So what we actually want is for the autoWidth to work proplerly.

FInally, I looked at the component and at the renderer, and it is obvious the auto-width mechanism does not work in the backend side.
The backend side only builds some JSON like data that the primefaces javascript builder can use to properly tune on the browser the behavior of the widget.

If you loook at primefaces 6.0 source code, the bug is in META-INF\resources\primefaces\forms

Search for the code that says the following:

> PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu Widget

In this javascript function hunt for the code chunk that says:

```
_render: function() {
        if(this.cfg.autoWidth) {
```

In this section of code your bug is the following line:

```
this.jq.css('min-width', this.input.outerWidth());
```

Here, I applied the following patch that hopefully should work in geting the drop down box to be as fat as the largest label:

```
 _render: function() {
        if(this.cfg.autoWidth) {
            // BEGIN: PATCHING 
            // ORIGINAL CODE:
            // this.jq.css('min-width', this.input.outerWidth());            
            // BUGFIX:
            // (a) compute the original min-with primefaces 6.0 would put on the root div
            var primefacesBugWidth = this.input.outerWidth();
            // (b) compute the length of the hidden select element  with all the labels inside of it
            var widthOfHiddenDivWithSelectLabels = this.jq.find('div select').width();
            var widthOfTheDropDownTriangle = this.jq.find('.ui-selectonemenu-trigger.ui-state-default.ui-corner-right').width();
            var widthOfLabelPlusTraingle = widthOfHiddenDivWithSelectLabels + widthOfTheDropDownTriangle;
            // (c) we will use whichever length is longer
            // in bug-fixed primefaces version the outerWidth should be computed correctly
            // but this seems not to be the case 
            var maxWidthOfTwoPossibleOptions = primefacesBugWidth > widthOfLabelPlusTraingle ? primefacesBugWidth : widthOfLabelPlusTraingle;
            this.jq.css('min-width', maxWidthOfTwoPossibleOptions);
            // END: PATCHING
        }        
    }
```

The idea of the code above is:
(a) look at the hidden div with all labels and get the width of that div
(b) add to that length the width needed for the primefaces triangle facing down
(c) compare the width we have computed to that that is suggested by primefaces and that seems to be way too small

NOTE:
To install the patch you have to copy all of the Primaces code for the SelectOneWidget.
Add it to a javascript file under your control.
Make sure you only run the compilation of your javascript file after the primefaces javascript file has been loaded.

Normally primefaces is being rendered at the HEAD.
So if you have you jasvacript as the last ement in the body you should be fine.

The patching is working fine for me.
THis is code I do not like to maintain however.

Comment: I suspect in the premium versions of primefaces this bug is no longer there. Can someone confirm the status for primefaces 6.12?

Comment: 99Sono this bug still exist in PF 6.12.  Why not submit your patch to the GitHub issues page?  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: If I remember correctly, on the primefaces github "issues" there had existed some sort of discussion where I had commented on it and had provided the link to this fix here. I believe it was the case for this particular issue. The appropriate thing would be do a pull request - that is true - but I would have to find the time for this. And I assumed that with a comment submission, the Optimmusprime would for sure fix the payed version of primefaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can ID the element and change the style width through CSS. Make it 100% of its container.

Answer (score 1):

If your `p:selectOneMenu` is in a DIV with an assigned width, I find setting `style="width:100%;"` on the `p:selectOneMenu` seems to work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be min-width, which is set in the rendered HTML. If that is your case, use a CSS selector fixed-width like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="fixed-width" ...
```

then define CSS

```
.fixed-width { min-width: 100% !important; }
```

That sets the width of the selectOneMenu widget to the width of the parent element. To have it work, parent elements's width should not be 'auto'.

Answer (score 0):

Those who still got problem with selectonemenu may try this

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    min-width: 0 !important;
}
```

Perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

style="min-width: 12rem"